# Android Layout design tips

Tags: android, listview

For a school project, I try to implement a design for an Android application.

Image 1:

[image]

Image 2:

[image]

As you can see, I have a list with some items. When the user clicks on an item, a little detailpage appear under the clicked item. Actually, I'm not sure if I should use a ListView in my example.
Creating a ListView with all items works for me. But for the detail information, I don't know what to do.

Are there some tips & tricks for designing this page?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would request to all, **please don't close this question**, rather let's welcome him as he is new to Stackoverflow. Good thing is that he has asked a question with enough details. Welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ExpandableListView see references [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

Comment: Yeah, but can I show the detail information with this layout?

Comment: Yes you can it is about how do you construct cell layout for header and subheader put Textview there....

Answer (score 0):

You could use custom `BaseAdapter`, on `getViewTypeCount()` return 2 and depending on click, changing the clicked list element type, invalidate list, and on `getView()` generate view depending on `itemType`. No animation though.

Comment: Why should I use this instead of an Expandable ListView?

Comment: if u need animation to open detail, use Expandable, if not u could use custom Adapter